# Cocos2dx crash on Nexus 7, android 4.2.1

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x, nexus-7

i have a problem with cocos2dx and android 4.2.1
My app works fine on platforms before 4.2, but on my nexus there are this errors:

```
02-07 16:55:06.691: W/dalvikvm(10381): Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/ArrayStoreException;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/ArrayStoreException;)
02-07 16:55:06.691: W/dalvikvm(10381): Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/ArrayStoreException;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/ArrayStoreException;)
02-07 16:55:06.711: W/dalvikvm(10381): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c74930)
02-07 16:55:06.711: W/System.err(10381): java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String cannot be stored in an array of type java.lang.String[][]
02-07 16:55:06.711: W/System.err(10381):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeTouchesEnd(Native Method)
02-07 16:55:06.711: W/System.err(10381):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.handleActionUp(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:129)
02-07 16:55:06.711: W/System.err(10381):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView$9.run(Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java:255)
02-07 16:55:06.711: W/System.err(10381):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1462)
02-07 16:55:06.711: W/System.err(10381):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
02-07 16:55:06.711: D/FlurryAgent(10381): Error logged: uncaught
02-07 16:55:06.711: D/FlurryAgent(10381): Ending session
02-07 16:55:06.711: E/AndroidRuntime(10381): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 556
02-07 16:55:06.711: E/AndroidRuntime(10381): java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.String cannot be stored in an array of type java.lang.String[][]
02-07 16:55:06.711: E/AndroidRuntime(10381):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeTouchesEnd(Native Method)
02-07 16:55:06.711: E/AndroidRuntime(10381):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.handleActionUp(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:129)
02-07 16:55:06.711: E/AndroidRuntime(10381):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView$9.run(Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java:255)
02-07 16:55:06.711: E/AndroidRuntime(10381):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1462)
02-07 16:55:06.711: E/AndroidRuntime(10381):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Please help, i cant understand what's wrong.

Comment: Please try to check using ndk stack

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

edit AnalyticXStringUtilAndroid.cpp (diwu/AnalyticX) 
line 24

```
jStringCls = pEnv->FindClass("[Ljava/lang/String;");
```

replace to

```
jStringCls = pEnv->FindClass("java/lang/String");
```